# Open file from integrated terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have VS Code setup with WSL on my Windows 10 machine. I am trying to find the command I can use to open an existing file from the integrated terminal in the current VS Code window.

I tried `code filename`, which launches a new VS Code window. I tried with `code -r filename`, but it also launches a new window.

Is there a way to quickly open a file when I'm focussed on the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.43.1, this appears to now work as expected, without additional add ons.